# Android Sensor Specs: Units, Full Scale

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

Good afternoon guys,

I am developing an Android application (more precisely WearOS) that accesses the sensor data of a device.

Sadly, I could not find out which **unit** the returned values have and which **full scale** a sensor is configured to use.

As you can see in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#public-methods_1), there are some getters which return information about a particular sensor, e.g. vendor, name or resolution. But I think the **unit** and **full scale** are missing or am I missing something? Where can I find these information?

E.g. the full scale of the accelerometer in my watch can be configured in the following ways: +-2/4/8/16g (based on its spec sheet). But Android doesn't give me this information.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**
Units are listed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion).
Only the question about full scale remains.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion

Comment: Thanks mate. I have overlocked that... But there are only the units. Do you also know something about finding the full scale?

Comment: My guess is that it varies by hardware.

Comment: Yeah, of course it does. But if you look at hardware specs, there is often a configurable value: [Example of a sensor datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6dso.pdf) (that's the acceleration sensor in my watch). E.g. on Arduino I can easily change register values to change the full scale or at least read it. I really need the information about the sensor's configuration for my master's thesis :(

Comment: "But if you look at hardware specs, there is often a configurable value" -- contact the manufacturer for your hardware of interest and see if they have published specs. AFAIK, Google does not maintain a document outlining the sensor specs for all 26,000+ Android device models.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I hoped I could easily read that value with a getter or something, because it should be deposited in a register directly on the device. So there should technically be no need for such a database.
But thank you anyways :) You helped me a lot!

Comment: Ah! OK, I understand your problem better now. There are some functions on `Sensor`, such as [`getMaximumRange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#getMaximumRange()), that may relate to what you want. Unfortunately, they are largely undocumented.

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem with the `getMaximumRange()` method. The documentation is not useful at all (for me). I have tried it and got a value of 34.905556 for the accelerometer and 156.x for the gyroscope. I would guess that I have to divide these numbers by 2 to get the actual range, so e.g. for the accelerometer: +-17.x. I would assume this number corresponds to the +-16g full scale of the sensor data sheet with some unidentifiable overhead. But this assumption doesn't work quite well if I am looking at the gyroscope, where the halve of the value has no obvious counterpart in the data sheet.